# Is my reasoning classifying gaussian primes right?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, unique-factorization-domains, gaussian-integers

what I want to prove:
if $a+bi$ （both a and b are nonzero）is gaussian prime,then $N(a+bi)$ is prime integer.

I know the fact that if $a+bi$ is gaussian prime ,then its norm must have the form $p^2$ or $p$. Then I should prove the former is impossible,provided that $a$ and $b$ are both nonzero.

aussming $N(a+bi)=p^2$ ,we could claim that $p$ is a gaussian prime,if not,then $p$ could be factored into two irreducible element,in which case $(a+bi)(a-bi)=$**product of more than two irreducible element**, which is impossible because of the property of UFD.

So $p$ must be gaussian prime,in which case we could use the unique factorization to prove $(a+bi)$ is associate to $p$,contradicting the assumption.

**is my reasoning right or not?**

Comment: If you know that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a UFD then yes you can say $p^2 = (a+ib)(a-ib)$ where $a+ib$ is a prime element $\implies p = u(a+ib)$ for some $u \in \mathbb{Z}[i]^\times$. But the same stays true even in non-UFD ring of integers, with prime ideal instead of  prime element.